# intersection of two subsets of vectors and its geometrical meaning

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

E and F is a subset of $ \mathbb R^3$.

How to compute $ P = E \cap F $ ? 
What is the geometrical meaning of E, F and P ?

$  E =\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1  \\
2  \\
-3  \end{array} \right)+\alpha\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1  \\
0  \\
1  \end{array} \right)+\beta  \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1  \\
1  \\
1  \end{array} \right)  $

$  F =\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
-2  \\
1  \\
4  \end{array} \right)+\gamma\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0  \\
1  \\
1  \end{array} \right)+\delta  \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
-1  \\
3  \\
2  \end{array} \right)  $

Comment: None of $\;E\,,\,F\;$ is a subspace: they both are planes, and they're either paralell or their intersection is a line...

Answer (score 2):

$E, F$ are certainly subsets of $\mathbb R^3.\,$ You'll find that each of $E, F$ defines a *plane* in $\mathbb R^3$.

See the following video to better understand [vector and parametric representations of planes](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ng8uqyxjliM).

Two planes in $\mathbb R^3$ will may be coincident (define the same planes), or be parallel and not coincident (hence have an empty intersection such that $P = E \cap F = \varnothing$), or else the planes will intersect in a *line* $P$.

[This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SoSTdgqknvY) will help you learn how to "solve" for the line of intersection of two planes: In involves the **cross product**. It's an excellent video.

Comment: sounds logical that vectors in $ \mathbb R^3 $ defining planes and their intersection is a line or they are parallel planes. But how to compute the intersection of these two planes ?

Answer (score 0):

To find the intersection, the analytic way would be to write out both planes as equations of the form $ax + by + cz + d = 0$, equate the left hand sides of each plane's equations with each other, and solve for x, y, and z.